# Spark in Scala: how do I compare two columns to number of locations where they are different?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in Spark called `df`. I have trained and machine learning model on a couple features and simply want to compute the accuracy between the `label` and `prediction` column.

```
scala> df.columns
res32: Array[String] = Array(feature1, feature2, label, prediction)
```

This would be mind-numbingly simple in numpy:

```
accuracy = np.sum(df.label == df.prediction) / float(len(df))
```

Is there a similarly easy way to do this in Spark using Scala?

I should also mention I'm completely new to Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.avg
import spark.implicits._
```

Example data:

```
val df = Seq((0, 0), (1,  0), (1, 1), (1, 1)).toDF("label", "prediction")
```

Solution:

```
df.select(avg(($"label" === $"prediction").cast("integer")))
```

Result:

```
+--------------------------------------+
|avg(CAST((label = prediction) AS INT))|
+--------------------------------------+
|                                  0.75|
+--------------------------------------+
```

Add:

```
.as[Double].first
```

or

```
.first.getDouble(0)
```

if you need a local value. If you want to count replace:

```
avg(($"label" === $"prediction").cast("integer"))
```

with

```
sum(($"label" === $"prediction").cast("integer"))
```

or

```
count(when($"label" === $"prediction", true))
```